# What is .c.obj / .cpp.obj file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation

I got these console output while compilation via GCC.

```
Building CXX object  xxxxxxx.cpp.obj
```

What are the `.cpp.obj` files? Are they the *object* file? Do the same as the `.o` file?

Comment: How exactly are you building?

Comment: @dbush Hi, the makefile is generated from cmake, shall I do the cmake tag?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo if .obj is the object file.

Comment: @JustWe It is. `obj` is short for object. You may also see `.o`.

Comment: Use [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) to determine file type.

Comment: @KamilCuk `xxxxx.c.obj: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is .c.obj / .cpp.obj file?

Object files created from compiling `.c` and `.cpp` files respectively.

> What are the .cpp.obj files?

See above.

> Are they the object file?

Yes.

> Do the same as the .o file?

Yes.

Note that "extension" is just part of a filename and is customizable. You can name your file anything you want you want, it will not affect the content. In cmake see [CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_OUTPUT_EXTENSION.html).